# Google Maps - Geocoding with Draggable marks and search box

Tags: google-maps, draggable

I'm new here and **i'm starting now with API code**

I'm trying to improve the code I've created.
**I have a window where you can enter the URL and a search button**

```
<div class="input-append">
<input id="gadres" type="text" size="16" onclick="this.select();"placeholder="Via/Piazza, Comune" class="span2" />
<button title="Trova le Coordinate" onclick="codeAddress();" class="btn" type="button">Cerca</button>
</div>
```

**a marker is shown on the map and the coordinates in two boxes below**.

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div> <label for="lat">Latitude</label>
<input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" required >
<label for="lng">Longitude</label>
<input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" required >
```

If I want to try a different point I can click on the map and I get the new set of coordinates. This is the code and it's WORK!!!

```
var map;
    var geocoder;
    var marker;

    function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.1471, 12.6342);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        myOptions);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng, 
      map: map
  });

map.streetViewControl=false;

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    marker.setPosition(event.latLng);

    var yeri = event.latLng;
    document.getElementById('lat').value=yeri.lat().toFixed(6);
    document.getElementById('lng').value=yeri.lng().toFixed(6);

  });
    }

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("gadres").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        document.getElementById('lat').value=results[0].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6);
        document.getElementById('lng').value=results[0].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6);
var latlong = "(" + results[0].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6) + " , " +
    + results[0].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6) + ")";


 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: latlong
    });

        marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(16);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

      } else {
        alert("impossibile trovare la lang e la lat del punto");
      }
    });
  }
```

Now, however, I would like to improve it.

1. I would like in the search box there was an auto-complete feature
2. and then the marker can be moved by changing the coordinates.

I'm just starting with the code and I try to change some parts on my code with this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox but I can not adapt it to my code. 
I have also the problem of making marker draggable but i don't understand where i must to put "draggable command"

Comment: To have draggable marker create marker with `draggable: true` property or using command `marker.setDraggable(true);`

Comment: Ok try to change `marker = new google.maps.Marker({` adding `draggable: true` but now my map don't work